# How big was the Order of the Phoenix during each of the two Wizarding Wars?

Tags: harry-potter

The Order Members we know best of all and spend most time with are of course those closest to the Trio, but we often come across mentions and appearances of other Order members during either of the wars, such as Benjy Fenwick, Caradoc Dearborn from the First War and Emmeline Vance and Elphias Doge from the Second War, which seems to lend credence to the idea that there were more than just the extended Weasley Clan (as of the Epilogue) who were involved with the Order.

Has there any information about how large the Order was during the two Wizarding Wars, specially the Second Wizarding War?

Comment: Have you tried Harry Potter Wikia? It's almost universally hated (I guess due to its canon policies) but is likely to have the full list, if it exists.

Comment: All I know is that it was fairly small, but then that is quite an ambiguous phrase, so I'm not too sure

Comment: @MacCooper I did, and it had a list of around 30-40 people (mostly the Weasley Family group + a few others) for both Wars combined, which really seems too narrow and too little to be the extent of the entire Resistence; and also had a couple of 'unidentified members' from movie visuals, so I was hoping for any concrete info about how big exactly the Order was, from interviews or Pottermore etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Original Order of the Phoenix

Moody shows Harry a photo of the original Order of the Phoenix, which includes quite a few names (highlighted in bold):

> “Original Order of the Phoenix,” growled Moody. “Found it last night when I was looking for my spare Invisibility Cloak, seeing as Podmore hasn’t had the manners to return my best one…. Thought people might like to see it.”
>
> Harry took the photograph. A small crowd of people, some waving at him, others lifting their glasses, looked back up at him.
>
> “**There’s me**,” said Moody unnecessarily, pointing at himself. The Moody in the picture was unmistakable, though his hair was slightly less gray and his nose was intact. “And there’s **Dumbledore** beside me, **Dedalus Diggle** on the other side… That’s **Marlene McKinnon**, she was killed two weeks after this was taken, they got her whole family. That’s **Frank and Alice Longbottom**—”
>
> Harry’s stomach, already uncomfortable, clenched as he looked at Alice Longbottom; he knew her round, friendly face very well, even though he had never met her, because she was the image of her son, Neville.
>
> “Poor devils,” growled Moody. “Better dead than what happened to them… and that’s **Emmeline Vance**, you’ve met her, and that there’s **Lupin**, obviously… **Benjy Fenwick**, he copped it too, we only ever found bits of him… shift aside there,” he added, poking the picture, and the little photographic people edged sideways, so that those who were partially obscured could move to the front.
>
> “That’s **Edgar Bones**… brother of Amelia Bones, they got him and his family too, he was a great wizard… **Sturgis Podmore**, blimey, he looks young… **Caradoc Dearborn**, vanished six months after this, we never found his body… **Hagrid**, of course, looks exactly the same as ever… **Elphias Doge**, you’ve met him, I’d forgotten he used to wear that stupid hat… **Gideon Prewett**, it took five Death Eaters to kill him and his brother Fabian, they fought like heroes… budge along, budge along . . .”
>
> The little people in the photograph jostled among themselves, and those hidden right at the back appeared at the forefront of the picture.
>
> “That’s Dumbledore’s brother, **Aberforth**, only time I ever met him, strange bloke… That’s **Dorcas Meadowes**, Voldemort killed her personally… **Sirius**, when he still had short hair… and… there you go, thought that would interest you!”
>
> — *Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 9 (*The Woes of Mrs. Weasley*)

I count 18 people in that photograph. There are a few people who aren’t listed, but we know or can assume were members of the original Order:

- **Lily and James Potter**
- **Peter Pettigrew** (seen in a photo in the film adaptation)
- **Minerva McGonagall**

There are also some individuals whose participation in the first war is unknown. They were all members of the reconstituted Order, but we don’t know either way if they were part of the original Order.

- **Arthur and Molly Weasley**
- **Mundungus Fletcher**
- **Severus Snape.** Although he turned spy before Voldemort’s downfall, it’s not clear if he was inducted into the Order before the end of the War.
- **Arabella Figg.** She was watching Harry since he moved to Privet Drive, so she was affiliated with Dumbledore since the First War, but we don’t know if she was part of the Order.
- **Olympe Maxime.** Definitely part of the second-order, as she accompanies Hagrid on his envoy to the giants, but no evidence either way about whether she was in the original Order.
- **Hestia Jones.** She was trusted to retrieve Harry in *Order of the Phoenix*, so was definitely part of the reconstituted Order.

So we can guess that there were maybe **25-or-so people in the First Order**. There will be people not seen in the photo above or listed independently, but it won’t be a huge number.

### Reconstituted Order of the Phoenix

We lose 8 people from the photograph due to death, and we never see Aberforth either. Lily and James were both killed, and Pettigrew defected.

The ambiguous people listed above get added to the total, which adds 7 to the total.

But of course, new people get recruited, including:

- **Kingsley Shacklebolt and Tonks.** They definitely weren’t in the original Order:

  > “We’ve managed to convince a couple of people, though,” said Mr. Weasley. “Tonks here, for one — she’s too young to have been in the Order of the Phoenix last time, and having Aurors on our side is a huge advantage — Kingsley Shacklebolt’s been a real asset too. He’s in charge of the hunt for Sirius, so he’s been feeding the Ministry information that Sirius is in Tibet.”
  >
  > — *Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 5 (*The Order of the Phoenix*)
- **Bill and Charlie Weasley**, both of whom would have been too young for the First War.

The pool has thinned somewhat, and I’d guess that it’s **more like 20-or-so at the start of the second war**, but obviously some of these people get killed as the war continues.

Honourable mentions must also go to Harry, Ron, Hermione, Fred and George, and Ginny, who all fought alongside the Order in the second War, but I don’t know if they were ever formally inducted.

---

*I do not claim this is a complete list of members – I’m sure I’ve missed a few – but I believe it is complete enough to get rough estimates for numbers.*

Comment: Would you count Amelia Bones or Fabian Prewett?  They are mentioned in the quote but not highlighted.

Comment: @TGnat: I’d probably put them in the “ambiguous” category, but I forgot to call them out explicitly.

Comment: how do they "formally induct"???

Comment: @AwalGarg In the books, there's a discussion about how Harry can't technically join the Order because he's underage (and then the Trio goes on the run a day after he's of age). The same would probably apply to Ginny. It wouldn't apply to Hermione and Ron, and Fred and George, tho.

Comment: `and we never see Aberforth either` — we do, in the DH book.

Comment: @Ruslan I meant as part of the Order of the Phoenix. When we see him in *Deathly Hallows*, he's trying to keep his head down and out of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

A full list seems to be found [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Phoenix#Members_of_the_Order). 36 people occur on the list, including both Dumbledores, Alice Longbottom, Arabella Figg, the Weasleys, Dedalus Diggle, Dorcas Meadowes and others

Comment: We generally frown upon answers that only point to external links. It would be great if you could summarize the most important facts from your linked source.

Comment: Thanks, ZenLogic. However, it seems to me the list is for both wars combined, which seems too little. Plus, many members on that list are people revealed in random one-off mentions or encounters, which opens up the possibility of there being members _not_ randomly mentioned or encountered. So what I'm hoping for is some info, if it exists, about size of the Order, that is more than simply counting up the named members from the books (unless there's some canon indicating there are no OotP members other than those named in the books, which would also be of interest)

Comment: I don't have the books with me right now, but I am sure  I remember mention that they were always a small group (what with people being afraid to go against Voldemort) I will have to take a look when I have access to my books again and let you know)

Comment: The list currently has 39 people.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of *Order of the Phoenix* Ron mentions that they've met about twenty members, and he thinks there are more:

> “Is anyone going to bother telling me what the Order of the Phoenix — ?”
>
> “It’s a secret society,” said Hermione quickly. “Dumbledore’s in charge, he founded it. It’s the people who fought against You-Know-Who last time.”
>
> “Who’s in it?” said Harry, coming to a halt with his hands in his pockets.
>
> “Quite a few people — ”
>
> “ — we’ve met about twenty of them,” said Ron, “but we think there are more...”

In the beginning of *Deathly Hallows* Mr. Weasley confirms that there are about twenty members:

> Mr. Weasley had explained that after the death of Dumbledore, their Secret-Keeper, each of the people to whom Dumbledore had confided Grimmauld Place's location had become a Secret-Keeper in turn.
>
> "And as there are around twenty of us, that greatly dilutes the power of the Fidelius Charm.

In the beginning of *Order of the Phoenix* Moody shows Harry a picture of the original order. The book mentions 21 different people in the picture (alexwlchan's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64326/100430) which counted 18 people in the picture left out James Lily and Pettigrew who are mentioned in a later paragraph). We can probably assume that the picture is a pretty good representation of the Order because Moody says:

"“That’s Dumbledore’s brother, Aberforth, only time I ever met him, strange bloke...

This seems to indicate that they went to some effort to make sure that all the members were present for the picture.

As a few of the members in the first war had died, and a few members in the second war did not participate in the first war, the total number didn't change that much. Thus in both of its iterations, the Order of the Phoenix seems to have had slightly more than 20 members.